# StackOverflow profile summary bug today 2012-12-06

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-summary

[image: profile screenshot]

As can be seen above, the time is way past 06:00 UTC but the reputation summary *still* hasn't updated? In fact it's accumulating from midnight the day before.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue?

Comment: I can't confirm for SO because I didn't have a net reputation change yesterday, but my stats here on Meta reset for the day.

Comment: I can confirm, I'm seeing exactly the same thing - my summary currently says I've got 580 for the day. If only!

Comment: @Jon Thanks for dropping by to gloat. Some people... :)

Comment: Probably the job responsible for resetting this has crashed, hopefully Nick will revive it soon!

Comment: #$%^%*$&@!@#$!@#$@!!

Comment: Sounds hopeful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah...that job ate it last night due to another one going *nucking futz* on our database (the  SE.com nightly leagues refresh).  We have plans for the nightly leagues to be offloaded completely but it's still a week or two out at best.

For now, we've deployed a stop-gap for the leagues issue and I've manually fixed today's totals.

Insignificant programmer porn: since that reputation overhaul a while back, we can now do this (yay!):

```
Update u
   Set u.ReputationToday = t.RepToday
From Users u
     Join (Select UserId, Sum(RepChange) as RepToday
             From RepHistory
            Where CreationDate >= Cast(GETUTCDATE() as Date)
         Group By UserId) t On u.Id = t.UserId
```