# Today's reputation includes yesterday's

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackOverflow profile summary bug today 20121206](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157796/stackoverflow-profile-summary-bug-today-20121206)

My reputation for the day seems to include yesterday's reputation too. Not sure if this has been reported before or if this is a known behaviour.

[image]

Comment: @Mysticial Weird I did not see it when searching. Shall I delete?

Comment: Nah, just let it close. This one has a better title.