# Today's reputation includes yesterday's

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, reputation

I'm seeing this today on my profile:

[image]

My reputation for the day should be 9 (as in the bottom of the screen) but shows as 254 in the popup window at the top.

Note that this is similar to [this other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157802/todays-reputation-includes-yesterdays).

Comment: Yup, this has happened before; a certain script failed to run. The Users tab (showing week, month, year, etc. rep gain) also needs a booting; the year 2012 is definitely gone now!

Comment: Interestingly enough, things are fine here on MSO; it's just SO that lost track of time.

Comment: The script seems to have worked for some people, so Jon Skeet (as a random example) has 195 rep for this year, while others have 100k. That's unusual.

Comment: @BoPersson: Nick Craver kicked something, but it doesn't appear to be complete yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the first time the script ran to reset all columns including the year...it didn't go well.  I've manually run it for today's totals (yay for a year being easy), enjoy.

Note the week value still rests on Sunday, so you have more reputation this week than this year so far - that's intentional.

Comment: Is the script still running? The current month, quarter and year numbers are rather skewed still. :-)

Comment: No changes in 40 minutes; something went wrong, Nick! :-/

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I corrected the script, null mismatch - all should be well now.

Comment: That looks a lot better and accurate. :-) Thanks!